# Why do I need hg update after hg pull while in git I'm doing only git pull

Tags: git, mercurial

In `git` to pull and use the latest changes to my local repository I'm using `git pull`.

In `hg`, I also use `hg pull` but it prints then

**run 'hg update' to get a working copy**

I do run `hg update` but I wonder why is this difference from `git`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The other answers don't actually answer the question, which is: why don't Git and Mercurial work the same?  Is there a philosophical difference?

In Mercurial, `pull` is the opposite of `push`: it syncs the local repo with a remote repo without touching the working copy.  So it's more consistent.

In Git, `pull` is a `fetch` plus a `merge`, or a `pull` plus an `update` in Mercurial terms.  Usually this is what you want.  So it's more efficient.

The [Distributed Version Control University talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k2vLKOUb8s) has a slide at the [4-minute mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k2vLKOUb8s#t=4m) that clearly demonstrates the way Mercurial works.  Michael Ernst's [Version control concepts and best practices](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/version-control.html) has a similar diagram (included below):

[image: Distributed version control]

Answer (score 25):

Because `git pull` internally performs `git fetch` and `git merge`, whereas `hg pull` only does what `git fetch` does. Just do `hg pull -u` instead. See also this [command equivalence table](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table).

Git fetch and mercurial pull do the same thing. Mercurial fetch and git pull do the same thing.

Of course Mercurial and Git use different data structures internally, so at some point there is a technical difference in the implementation details. If you really care deeply about it, just compare the documentation for [hg pull](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#pull) and [git fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html). The Git wording is more technical and verbose, but in the end it is the same.

Answer (score 3):

To get equivalent git functionality enable the fetch Mercurial extension (bundled with Mercurial distributions), see [fetch extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FetchExtension).  It will execute a `hg pull -u`.